# Android ArrayAdapter: how to delete an item from within the adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

In my App I have two lists of vehicles: full list and my favorites. When In favorites I show the option for the user to delete the vehicle from this favorites:
[image]

To show this custom listview item I implemented the following adapter:

```
public class VehicleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Vehicle> {


    private int listType=1;

    public Vehicle[] vehicles;

    public VehicleAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull Vehicle[] objects, int listType) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.listType = listType;
        this.vehicles = objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_row, null);

        Vehicle vehicle = getItem(position);

        ImageView imgVehicle = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imgVehicle);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtDescription = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

        txtTitle.setText(vehicle.name);
        txtDescription.setText(vehicle.short_description);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(vehicle.picture).into(imgVehicle);

        // If it's the favorites list
        if(listType == 2) {
            Button btnDelete = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            final int itemPosition = position;
            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Vehicle item = VehicleAdapter.this.vehicles[itemPosition];
                    remove(item); // HERE: throws fatal error
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

        return customView;
    }
}
```

How I instantiate the adapter in the fragment (I'm loading the list inside a fragment):

```
Vehicle[] items = new Vehicle[vehicles.size()];
items = vehicles.toArray(items);

ListAdapter vehicleAdapter = new VehicleAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.vehicle_row, items, mListType);

final ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(vehicleAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Vehicle vehicle = (Vehicle) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).loadVehicleInformation(vehicle);
    }
});
```

The exception:

```
Exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
java.util.AbstractList.remove (AbstractList.java:638)
java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove (AbstractList.java:75)
java.util.AbstractCollection.remove (AbstractCollection.java:229)
android.widget.ArrayAdapter.remove (ArrayAdapter.java:244)
xx.xx.xxxxxx.VehicleAdapter.remove (VehicleAdapter.java:78)
xx.xx.xxxx.VehicleAdapter$1.onClick (VehicleAdapter.java:62)
android.view.View.performClick (View.java:4756)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:19749)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5221)
```

My problem: I'm not sure if I'm using the right approach with the delete button. As you can see I add a listener to it in the adapter class. I can get the right item but when I try to remove it throws a fatal error. I believe I'm using the wrong approach but I'm lost on how I could do this delete option.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please also post logcat errors and your remove() method.

Comment: It would be useful if you show the few line of codes that instantiate the adapter inside your App. The issue may be related the way the adapter is instantiated and the exception appears at runtime when you try to modify the live content of the instantiated adapter.

Comment: @Livio I just added in the question

Comment: You should change your code because **Vehicle[]** _items_ cannot be modified, so instead you should have something like **ArrayList<Vehicle>** _items_, that is modifiable and will not generate the exception

Comment: Thanks @Livio that was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sending, Verhicle[] send as ArrayList, if we send as an array it can't be modified in ArrayAdapter.

```
public class VehicleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Vehicle> {

    private int listType=1;

    public ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public VehicleAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Vehicle> objects, int listType) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.listType = listType;
        this.vehicles = objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_row, null);

        final Vehicle vehicle = getItem(position);

        ImageView imgVehicle = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imgVehicle);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtDescription = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

        txtTitle.setText(vehicle.name);
        txtDescription.setText(vehicle.short_description);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(vehicle.picture).into(imgVehicle);

        // If it's the favorites list
        if(listType == 2) {
            Button btnDelete = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    remove(vehicle);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

        return customView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It gives me the same error: class java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Updated my answer, Have a look.

Comment: That was it. ArrayList was the right type for the objects. Thanks